# Unwanted JSON output before page load

Tags: php, jquery, json

Hi does anyone know how to stop json data from outputting in the browser before the page loads in? The data being echoed in included php script with

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

But 'echo' is what gives me access to the data in my $.ajax functions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sounds like a js syntax error to me. but with out seeing code, its any ones guess

Comment: Can you post a relevant excerpt of the generated HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you are saying in your question and your comment on an earlier answer, you have a `voting.php` script which includes another script, say `data.php`. The latter does `echo json_encode($row)`, which causes unwanted data in the output from `voting.php`. You want `voting.php` to load the data from `data.php` using the jQuery `$.ajax` function.

1. Don't include `data.php` in `voting.php`.
2. Make the necessary `$.ajax` calls after the page produced by `voting.php` has loaded, i.e. when the DOM is ready, using the jQuery ready event.

The ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // $.ajax call which loads data from data.php
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks @havard. It was happening because I was using the data twice, through the included script and also through the newly implemented $.ajax call which was bringing in JSON through the same included script.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code like this, it will only fire once the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP, by definition, can ONLY execute before the page loads.

If you give a little more info on what you're trying to accomplish, I'm sure you'll get some useful suggestions.

Comment: PHP (usually) executes _as_ the page loads, not before.

Comment: More like PHP executes and generates the page, which may or may not continue as the page is sent to the client.

Comment: Okay I have got a 'voting' page that brings in some JSON data through an $.ajax function. I get the data and use it fine. But its just that now before the voting page loads up the browser outputs the unwanted json data echo from the included php script.

Comment: Its weird because its seems to work fine on a desktop browser but the problem occurs testing on an iPhone. Thanks anyway guys.